# Very large timestamp

Tags: timestamp

I am having trouble converting a very large timestamp. Sample timestamp in question: 131226654560988101.

This is pulled from the IE History file WebCacheV01.dat under the column AccessedTime.

It doesn't appear to be microseconds or nanoseconds. And if it followed Chrome history timestamp standards, it would be microseconds from 1/1/1601. It is a timestamp way beyond that.

The timestamp should resolve to sometime in 2016. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I am leaving this question up for anyone else who may run into this issue.

The timestamp in question is the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since 1/1/1601 (http://www.epochconverter.com/ldap.) The proper term is called a file time/filetime.

More information can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx